# Correct configuration to build libsrtp for the iphone?

Tags: iphone, arm, configure, rtp

I'm trying to build libsrtp so that I can use it on the iPhone (I intend to use it with libav's implementation of RTP).

My configuration:

> ./configure
> --build='arm-apple-darwin9'

The warning I get when I attempt to call srtp_init():

> file was built for unsupported file
> format which is not the architecture
> being linked (armv7)

Followed by the error:

> "_srtp_init", referenced from:
>
> +[Manager initialize:] in Manager.o
>
> Symbol(s) not found

Does anyone know the proper configuration for building the library correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is it's not being built for ARM (or not for the right ARM; you need to look at which compiler is bing invoked with which options, and compare it to one you know is working).  Did you do rebuild configure with autoconf?  See the [GNU build system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) wiki page for a starting point on how to reconfigure the build for other systems/processors.

FYI, if you find a bug in the configure.in or other parts of libsrtp, please let me know - I'm an author on it with checkin privs.

Answer (score 0):

For general guidelines on cross compiling libraries for iOS I recommend this article:
http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-cross-compiling-libraries-for-ios-armv6armv7i386/

The same guy also wrote an updated version for iOS 5. This one is specific to the `tesseract` library, but the general principles are the same:
http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/.

Using these as a guide I've had some success compiling a few libraries. Key things to note are that you have to disable compiling shared binaries. Also I recommend using `clang` rather than `gcc`.